# Find a specific word in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a code that loads an ArrayList of Strings and checks to see if a specific word is used. This may sound weird but the specifics are:

Number of toots containing "toot" (with any capitalization and allowing zero (0) in place of oh (o), e.g., "to0t" should be counted too); however, you should not count a toot if it only contains "toot" as part of another work, e.g., "tooter" is not enough to count a toot.

I have tried many things but it still doesn't seem to work and count the proper results.

Here is what I have now after some help from members:

```
for (String toot : toots) {
        toot = toot.toLowerCase().replace("0", "o").trim();
        if(toot.equalsIgnoreCase("toot")){
           tootsWithToot++;
        }
}
```

An example would be with the "toot messages" (each line is a separate message):

**1 toot 2 t00t

toot

will be back

tooter tooting**

The results should show 2 as tooter and tooting aren't the word "toot" with the O or 0 variations.

I think a change should be that I need .contains but I'm not 100% sure.
Again, I apologize for this humorous request, I am still a novice programmer.

Comment: I can only see one instance of `toot` as `toots` and `t00ts` shouldn't be counted as per your example.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

The following should match your requirements. It uses regex to match obnly "whole word" occurrences of your string.

```
for (String toot : toots) {
    toot = toot.toLowerCase().replace("0", "o").trim();
    toot = toot.toLowerCase().replace("O", "o").trim();
    toot = toot.toLowerCase().replace("T", "t").trim();
    if(toot.matches(".*\\btoot\\b.*")){
        tootsWithToot++;
    }
}
```

A more pure regex example would be something like the following:

```
for (String toot : toots) {
    if(toot.matches(".*\\b[tT][oO0]{2}[tT]\\b.*")){
        tootsWithToot++;
    }
}
```

This regex matches instances of `toot`, ignoring the case of the t's `[tT]` and the o's (whilst also including 0) `[oO0]`, when they are surrounded by any word break character.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: You could also ignore case: (?i).*\bt[o0]{2}t\b.*

Comment: where did you get the image?

Comment: Wait, you changed it from your first response, would your VERY FIRST response always work?

Comment: @user3089390 My "very first' answer would not have always worked (assuming you mean before any edits). It did not take into account the case of `t` and `o`. The new code works perfectly however.